# LoginToBoggan & OneAll Social Login: one-time-login token email sent withoud need

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

When you have installed LoginToBoggan AND the OneAll Social Login modules (to enable login via Facebook, Google etc.) - they seem to work not nicely together.
LoginToBoggan provides a nice one-time-login token and Drupal sends out an email for every user to confirm the email address after signup.
But: when you signup with a e.g. Google Account, LoginToBoggan assumes that this email address is already confirmed and does NOT put the user in the `pre-authenticated` role - the user is authenticated at once...

There would be no problem with that, if the user did not get an email that asks him to confirm his mail address with a one-time link. And if the user clicks on that link, he gets a message on the page that this link is not valid, as the token "can only be used once" - as if it was already used.

When signing up just in Drupal (without Google, Facebook etc. SocialAll module), this email makes perfectly sense and the token works. It just does not work when signing up via SocialMedia.

Does anyone have a hint here? can I disable this mail under the circumstance that the account was created using the OneAll Social plugin? Where do I have to put that code in?

Any help appreciated.